# How to check that gpg checking is correct on RHEL based machines or not?

Tags: rhel, repository, gpg

How can I check that the "enabled=1" repositories have "gpgcheck=1" in the "/etc/yum.repos.d/" directory (and the "gpgkey=" file exist or not?)?

Q: **I'm searching for a solution to do this (oneliner?), I mean to list all the "enabled=1" repositories and "gpgcheck" status, and does the "gpgkey=XXX" file exist or not?** - the problem is that that one .repo file could contain several repositories!

p.s.: afaik the "gpgkey=XXX" -> XXX could only be a local file, not an url through http... but fix me if I'm wrong..

Comment: The oneliner will be ugly if rpm/yum don't have this functionality themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't think of any kind of simple way to do this. Whipped the following together, though it's not particularly elegant.

```
sed '/^\[.*\]/s,\[,\n<<[,' /etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo |
  awk '
    BEGIN { 
      RS = "\n<<"
    }
    /\nenabled=1/ && !/\ngpgcheck=1/ {
      print $1"~gpgcheck disabled for enabled repo"
    }
    /\nenabled=1/ &&  /\ngpgcheck=1/ && !/\ngpgkey=/ {
      print $1"~gpgcheck enabled for enabled repo, but missing gpgkey setting"
    }
    /\nenabled=1/ &&  /\ngpgcheck=1/ && /\ngpgkey=/ {
      print $1"~gpgcheck enabled for enabled repo, see output below for gpgkey file status"
    }
  ' | column -ts~

printf "\nChecking gpg keys for enabled repos\n"

sed '/^\[.*\]/s,\[,\n<<[,' /etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo |
  awk '
    BEGIN { 
      RS = "\n<<"
    }
    /\nenabled=1/ && /\ngpgcheck=1/ && /\ngpgkey=/
  ' |
    awk -F: /^gpgkey=/{print\$2} |
      xargs ls -l
```

Drop it into a script and you're off.